# Проверка существования таблицы перед записью в базу

Tags: sql, postgresql, golang

Ниже представлен кусок кода на go, проверка на существование таблицы в базе данных постгрес, подскажите минусы и плюсы данного кода если они есть. Существуют более простые и более быстрые проверки на go или его библиотеках ?

```
    db, err := sql.Open(Database9, Database0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)

    }

    defer db.Close()

    //Проверка ид на бан список
    var pppp string = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tgid_ban_id where id_telegram = '" + strconv.FormatUint(t.Idphone, 10) + "'"
    //log.Printf("pppp =", pppp)
    rows0 := db.QueryRow(pppp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var count0 int
    err = rows0.Scan(&count0)

    //log.Printf("count0(ban) = ", count0)

    if count0 >= 1 {
        log.Printf("BAN-" + strconv.FormatUint(t.Idphone, 10) + "_" + string(t.Android))
        return

    }
```

Comment: Вот в упор не вижу проверки на существование таблицы. Если имеется в виду "не получим ответа - значит, таблицы не существует" - ну так это неверно, других причин запросу не выполниться корректно предостаточно.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema

Answer (score 1):

Можно проверить через служебную таблицу статистики pg_stat_user_tables (pg_stat_all_tables)

```
    select shemaname,relname from pg_stat_user_tables where relname like 'id_telegram'
```

https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/monitoring-stats#pg-stat-all-tables-view